# stripe subscription 3d secure stripe.confirmPayment() already fails before pressing 3d secure complete

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I have stripe elements code for subscription that follows this.
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

The non 3ds credit cards work successfully. ie. 4242 4242 4242 4242.

### Problem

for the 3ds case, I use the test card `4000000000003220` via here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure/authentication-flow#three-ds-cards

1. i create a subscription. a.k.a. backend `stripe_client().Subscription.create()` function.
2. read the payment intent(via stripe dashboard) status = Payment started.
3. I fill in the 3ds test card info. `<form><PaymentElements />...`
4. Press Subscribe. a.k.a. `stripe.confirmPayment()` function.
5. read the payment intent(via stripe dashboard) status = 3D Secure attempt failed
   The customer failed 3D Secure authentication.

[image]

6. the 3d secure popup test window comes up. I did *not* press `Complete` or `Fail.`

how is the payment intent failed 3ds even before the popup window for 3ds to perform happen?

Answer (score 0):

Did you click on the cancel button on the top of the 3DS pop-up modal? If you did, it's also considered as a failed 3DS attempt.

Comment: no i did not. I see the 3ds pop up, I leave it as is. then I check the payment intent, and it already failed